# iOSSDK 8.3 is SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, xcode-6.2, ios8.3

Build on iOS8.3 is working watchApps, but not woring on iOS 8.2.
It's saying `"SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage"`

I tried XCODE Clean, delete from MyApps on the Simulator and rebuild.

Other thread says `"Info.plist  BundleIdentifier is same name"`, 
So I checking this file. It's same name.

Please help me why can't build WatchApp on iOS8.2.

Comment: where you able to find a solution to this? it's happening to me as well.